# Would this be a dual State Machine?

Tags: architecture, state, computer-science, state-machine

I am trying to find the right description for the type of state machine I am using.

I have my main state machine that controls the user interface. I.e When the user clicks 'Home' it goes to Home State. Clicking Next takes it to the 'Stats' state etc.

I also have a number of classes in my application doing analysis, each with their own state machine. The states would be something like: Set Up, Running, Completed, Error.

So when the user selects to view a particular 'Stat' they would select which index they would like to view. And based on the current internal state of that stat, the main state machine would change the user interface to the right window. If the internal state is 'Running' it will show a different tab as opposed to 'Completed' state.

I am trying to find what this kind of architecture would be referred to so I can do some more reading.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "hierarchical" state machine is the term you're looking for.  The Stats state contains substates Setup, Running, Completed, and Error.  While you're in one of the substates you are also within the parent or superstate.